# mysql PHP query question

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, i have a problem here...

I am sending values of drop down lists via ajax to this PHP file.

Now I want to search a mysql database using these values, which I have managed to do, BUT, only if I set the values to something...

Take a look:

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM cars_db WHERE price BETWEEN '$cars_price_from' AND '$cars_price_to' AND year BETWEEN '$cars_year_from' AND '$cars_year_to' AND mileage BETWEEN '$cars_mileage_from' AND '$cars_mileage_to' AND gearbox = '$cars_gearbox' AND fuel = '$cars_fuel'";
```

now, what if the user doesnt select any "price_from" or "year_from"... The fields are only optional, so if the user doesnt enter any "price from" or "year from", then the user wants ALL cars to show...

Do I have to write a query statement for each case or is there another way?

Comment: You asked essentially the same question 14 minutes before this one.  It is more efficient to edit the original question if you wish to clarify it.  Don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 4):

I do something similar to davethegr8 except I put my conditions in an array and then implode at the end just so I don't have to worry about which conditions got added and whether I need to add extra AND's.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM car_db";

// an array to hold the conditions
$conditions = array();

// for price
if ($car_price_from > 0 && $car_price_to > $car_price_from) {
    $conditions[] = "(price BETWEEN '$cars_price_from' AND '$cars_price_to')";
}
elseif ($car_price_from > 0) {
    $conditions[] = "(price >= '$cars_price_from')";
}
elseif ($car_price_to > 0) {
    $conditions[] = "(price <= '$cars_price_from')";
}
else { 
    //nothing
}

// similar for the other variables, building up the $conditions array.

// now append to the existing $sql
if (count($conditions) > 0){
    $sql .= 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply detect which parameters are missing in your PHP code and fill in a suitable default. eg

```
if (!isset($cars_mileage_to))
    $cars_mileage_to = 500000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build you query, adding the "where" part only if your variables are different from "".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560980/php-help-with-building-query/1561105#1561105

Answer (score 0):

or if you're using mysql 5.x, you can also use subselects:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

don't forget to validate the input.  It's trivial with firebug, for example, to inject some tasty sql.